# Image picker from Gallery

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing my first iOS application (iPhone only) with Swift. The main application view should allow the user to chose the image from the photo gallery.

I've found the following sample code of ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIImagePickerController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: { imageP in

    })
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    let selectedImage : UIImage = image
    println(selectedImage)
}
```

}

Comment: you integrated image picker to pick image. But you not mentioned what issue you are facing.